# Number of user that came back within 3 days after playing at least three sessions?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have data which contains user, eventdate and sessions.I want to separate users who had atleast 3 sessions and came back for new session within 3 days.

```
    user  eventdate   session
    A      2018-02-05   1
    A      2018-02-05   2
    A      2018-02-06   3 
    A      2018-02-10   4
```

The output the users who had done 3 sessions and then came back for forth session within 3 days.

I tried the following query but it is not giving me the answer that is needed.

```
 SELECT distinct user, MIN(eventdate) startdate, MAX(eventdate) enddate
FROM (SELECT user, eventdate
      FROM (SELECT user, eventdate
              FROM tablename
             where datediff(startdate,enddate)<=3
             ORDER BY user, eventdate) where sessions>=3) t
 GROUP BY user
 ORDER BY user, startdate;
```

I know the query has many issues but I am simply unable to figure out how to move forward. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is intended output? in above case for A all data appear. And does your query compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user, eventdate, sessions_in_a_day, 
    SUM(sessions_in_a_day) OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY eventdate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) total_sessions_before, 
    DATE_DIFF(eventdate, LAG(eventdate) OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY eventdate), DAY) delay
  FROM (
    SELECT user, eventdate, COUNT(1) sessions_in_a_day 
    FROM t
    GROUP BY user, eventdate
  )
)
WHERE total_sessions_before >= 3
AND delay <= 3
-- ORDER BY user, eventdate
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'A' user, DATE '2018-02-05' eventdate, 1 session UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2018-02-05', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2018-02-06', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2018-02-06', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2018-02-09', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2018-02-09', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2018-02-10', 7 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2018-02-13', 8 
)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user, eventdate, sessions_in_a_day, 
    SUM(sessions_in_a_day) OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY eventdate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) total_sessions_before, 
    DATE_DIFF(eventdate, LAG(eventdate) OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY eventdate), DAY) delay
  FROM (
    SELECT user, eventdate, COUNT(1) sessions_in_a_day 
    FROM t
    GROUP BY user, eventdate
  )
)
WHERE total_sessions_before >= 3
AND delay <= 3
ORDER BY user, eventdate
```

result is

```sql
Row user    eventdate   sessions_in_a_day   total_sessions_before   delay    

1   A       2018-02-09  2                   4                       3    
2   A       2018-02-10  1                   6                       1    
3   A       2018-02-13  1                   7                       3
```

Playing with WHERE clause you can "tune" to whatever case you need
In example above, you show only users who had at least 3 sessions before they reached next session within next 3 days
If you are interested in only those who had exactly 3 sessions and reached their fourth session - you can add respective filter

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Sess AS
(
select user, session
from tablename
group by  user
HAVING count(session) >= 3
)

select user
from tablename join Sess on tablename.session = Sess.session
group by user
having (datediff(day, min(eventdate), Max(eventdate)) <=3) 
and (min(eventdate) <> Max(eventDate))
```